# Problems displaying file (pdf or other) in PHP and/or other file

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table with the path and the name of a file (pdf or other). Next to that table I have an object with a pdf-file showing.

I want to change the object according to the rw on which the user clicked.

I've tried with javascript, but the displayed file does not change.

```
<td width='50%'><object id='CurBijl' data='Bijlage/2023/SV13303123 back.jpg' width='100%' height='850px'><p><h1>Unable to display file</h1</p></object></td>
```

javascript:

```
function ChangeBijlage(newBijlage)
{
document.getElementById("CurBijl").setAttribute("data", newBijlage);
}
```